# All network interfaces have disappeared

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, ethernet

I have 3 Ethernet interfaces and one WiFi card, everything had worked fine previously until, one day when I turned it on it failed to raise network interfaces. When I ran ifconfig -a all that came up was my loopback and bridge. I had not updated any software before turning it off last time. All recommended checks came up with only the bridge and loopback, I would like to know how to fix this problem. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.4 server.

cat /etc/network/interfaces outputs the following:

```
# Loopback 
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback  
# WAN interface 
auto enp10s0 
iface enp10s0 inet dhcp  
#Bridge (LAN) 
auto br0 
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.1.10.1
    network 10.1.10.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.1.10.255
    bridge_ports enp8s0
    post-up /usr/sbin/hostapd \
       -P /var/run/hostapd.$IFACE.pid \
       -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd-simple.conf
   pre-down cat /var/run/hostapd.$IFACE.pid | xargs kill
```

output from lshw -C network:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7304000-f7304fff memory:f7300000-f7303fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:b000(size=256) memory:f7204000-f7204fff memory:f7200000-f7203fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7400000-f7400fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7b00000-f7b03fff
```

Comment: Desktop or Server installation? What version Ubuntu? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `dkms status`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema lshw gave a lot of output, having trouble copying it down, but it looks like all of my interfaces are there. /etc/network/interfaces shows 
`# Loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# WAN interface
auto enp10s0
iface enp10s0 inet dhcp

#Bridge (LAN)
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
   address 10.1.10.1
   network 10.1.10.0
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 10.1.10.255
   bridge_ports enp8s0
   post-up /usr/sbin/hostapd \
      -P /var/run/hostapd.$IFACE.pid \
      -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd-simple.conf
  pre-down cat /var/run/hostapd.$IFACE.pid | xargs kill`

Comment: You have to copy/paste the output into your question... once there, select the pasted text and click the {} icon to format it to human-readable. You also didn't indicate Desktop or Server.

Comment: @heynnema i am using Ubuntu 16.04.4 server, i have added the output to the question

Comment: What about the other command outputs that I requested? Thanks.

Comment: I do not have netplan installed, and i am still working on copying down the output from lshw

Comment: Don't manually copy the lshw output. Copy/paste it.

Comment: dont have a way to copy/paste from my servers temporary monitor to my laptop without ssh, which requires i have a working network interface.

Comment: @heynnema lshw output added

Comment: It's not showing me the "logical name" or the driver. Three **separate** ethernet cards, yes? You haven't shown me `dkms status`. Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Your /etc/network/interfaces file is definitely incorrect.

Comment: @heynnema one pci card with two ports, one port on the motherboard and one wifi card, dkms is not installed

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, do `sudo lshw -C network | grep -i logical`.

Comment: Just to get a little ahead of myself, I suspect that there's a problem with your dual-port PCIe ethernet card. Carefully REMOVE it, and retry `sudo lshw -C network` and see if the remaining motherboard ethernet port has a "logical name" now. Show me that output.

Comment: Status please...